# Не запускается видео Youtube API

Tags: веб-программирование, google-chrome, youtube-api

На странице есть плеер Youtube api и пользователь может может вставлять ссылку на ютуб видео и проигрывать его. С компьютера всё работает отлично, но с других устройств включать видео не получается. Код прикрепляю. Видео включается с телефона, если прямо в коде выставить videoId, но на пользовательские ссылки не реагирует.

Также появляются ошибки, которые указаны в скриншоте. В интернете сказано, что возможная проблема — Adblock, но на этом сайте я его отключил.

Я новичок, поэтому прошу не ругаться на меня, если что неправильно объяснил, написал и т.п. Если необходимо, приложу больше информации. Буду рад помощи, советам
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
var tag = document.createElement('script');

tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

var player;
```

```
window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = function () {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
        height: '360',
        width: '640',
        videoId: "novideoid",
        events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange,
        }
    });
}
// 4. The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
function onPlayerReady(event) {
    event.target.playVideo();
}

// 5. The API calls this function when the player's state changes.
//    The function indicates that when playing a video (state=1),
//    the player should play for six seconds and then stop.
var done = false;
function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !done) {
        done = true;
    }
}
function stopVideo() {
    player.stopVideo();
}
document.getElementById("videoSrc").addEventListener("click", function () {

    var userVideoUrl = document.getElementById("userUrl").value;
    var userVideoId = getVideoId(userVideoUrl);
    
    if (userVideoId == "") {
        alert('Введите корректный url!');
    } else {
        connection.invoke("SendVideoData", userVideoId).catch(function (err) {
            return console.error(err.toString());
        });
    }
});
connection.on("ReceiveVideoData", function (userVideoId) {
    player.loadVideoById(userVideoId);
});
```